# Grub rescue after trying a reinstall (parallel boot with Windows 7)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, grubrescue, reinstalling

I had Windows 7 one disk. Then I installed ubuntu on a different disk. That went fine. But for various reasons, I wanted to reinstall ubuntu. So I booted my install disk and chose something akin to "reinstall ubuntu and remove files" (not the one that'd also remove Windows 7 files).

Well, the installation seemed to go just fine, but after it, I can't boot into either OS. All I'm met with is a prompt for "grub rescue", help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the boot-repair CD. It'll restore GRUB.

Comment: Care to elaborate? After all, using it started all this previously.